# Remove index.php and parameter name from URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Hi I am making a site where I want nice and clean links. I am trying to make a link with a get parameter look alot cleaner. Here is a sample link of how the link is at the moment:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?item=cd-player
```

Here is how I want the link to look:

```
http://www.example.com/cd-player
```

I have been able to get rid of index.php from the url to leave just the parameter but I need help in getting rid of the "?item" bit as well.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ /$1 [R,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /?item=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also, this may be a php code rather than a code for the .htaccess file, but if a user enters `http://www.example.com/cd-player`, how will it know that "cd-player" is the value of a get variable called "item"?

EDIT: The problem I am having with the answers below is that I am using the following code to remove file extensions and the code in the answers below treats the files as a query:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this. This will allow you to have clean links

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#This means if its not a real file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#This means if its not a real directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#Then take the capture and rewrite it
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?item=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You can add this if you are wanting to remove the php extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?item=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 rules actually:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?item=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?item=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: My problem is that other files in the same folder are being treated as a query now as I have removed file extension from all files please see edit

Comment: You need stronger rule than `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]` to add `.php` extension (see edit)